# Moodle Authentication Plugin. What am I missing?

Tags: php, authentication, plugins, single-sign-on, moodle

I am trying to manually authenticate an user in moodle using authentication plugins, but I don't understand everything that is needed for the whole process to work. So, some suggestions on what I am missing here would be very helpful!

I created the plugin, enabled it, and it worked, but only for SOME cases, and that is where my problem lies. My guess is that at some point I need to actually call a function that saves user information in the moodle database. But again, I'm not sure where it is, or how it works. So... experts, give me a hand here.

Here are the two functions I changed on my authentication plugin. (auth.php)

```
function loginpage_hook() {
    global $CFG, $DB, $user, $frm, $errormsg;
    $IsAuthenticated = false;
    if(isset($_COOKIE["AUTHENTICATION_KEY"])){
        $json = file_get_contents("WWW.WEBSERVICEURL.COM",true); 
        //getting the file content
        $decode = json_decode($json, true);
        //getting the file content as array  
        if($decode["AuthFlag"]){
            $ucUser = $decode["Username"];
            $user = $DB->get_record('user', array('username'=>$ucUser, 'mnethostid'=>$CFG->mnet_localhost_id));
            $frm->username = $ucUser;
            $IsAuthenticated = true;
        }
    }
    if(!$IsAuthenticated && empty($frm->username)){
        $errormsg = ".";
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if the username and password work or don't exist and false
 * if the user exists and the password is wrong.
 *
 * @param string $username The username
 * @param string $password The password
 * @return bool Authentication success or failure.
 */
function user_login ($username, $password) {
    global $CFG, $DB, $user;
    if(!$user){ return false; }

    if(isset($_COOKIE["AUTHENTICATION_KEY"])){
        $json = file_get_contents("WWW.WEBSERVICEURL.COM", true); 
        //getting the file content
        $decode = json_decode($json, true);
        //getting the file content as array  
        if($decode["AuthFlag"]){
            $ucUser = $decode["Username"];
            if($user->username = $ucUser){ return true; }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand exactly where your problem is and what are you trying to achieve. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: My problem was that when I tried to manually authenticate an user (trhough a webservice), it would not work for users that were not in the moodle database (if that makes any sence). So, what I was looking for was to create the user in the moodle database so that my manual authentication could work. Something like that. But I actually found a way around, the LDAP plugin that is already in use creates this moodle user, so... when trying to use my plugin, if the user doesnt exist, I tell moodle to use the LDAP one, and next time, since the user is now created, my plugin works. Thanks 4 ur help!

Answer (score 2):

I've receantly made an auth plugin. I think the key snippet of code that you are missing would be something like this:

```
$user = authenticate_user_login($username, null);

        $newuser = new stdClass();
        $newuser->id = $user->id;
        $newuser->email = $mail;
        $newuser->username = $mail;
        $newuser->country = 'AR';
        $newuser->city = 'capital federal';
        $newuser->firstname = $nombre;
                    $newuser->lastname =  $apellido;

        $DB->update_record('user', $newuser);

        $user = authenticate_user_login($mail, null);
        complete_user_login($user);
```

The key function there is `authenticate_user_login($username, null)`. You can  pass any username, if the username doesn't exist, it creates an empty user, ready to be filled up.

I have the plugin working just fine. So if you need something or you want to share your code so I can understand  where the problem is, you are welcome!

Comment: is it possible to make something that allows students from any school that uses moodle to login using their moodle sign in?  For example I have a college book rental app , id like to have a "sign in with moodle" button. Possible?

Comment: I think is possible, but I don't know if there is something like a plugin to do it. Since Moodle is open source you could add a service on Moodle to do that authentication. But is not that easy!